# The probability that the last ball in a box is white

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Inside a box there are $M$ black balls and $N$ white balls. Balls are taken out of the box one at time, I needed to calculate the probability the last ball taken out is white. The way I used was, each balls has the probability of $\frac{1}{M+N}$ to be taken out last and because there are $N$ white balls the probability I need is $\frac{N}{N+M}$, but when I looked at the answer in the book I saw $$P(last \space ball \space is \space white) = \frac{\binom{N+M-1}{N-1}}{\binom{N+M}{N}}=\frac{N}{N+M}$$ and I don't understand how the book got that equation, how is the number of ways to choose $N-1$ balls out of $N+M-1$ divided by the number of ways to choose $N$ balls out of $N+M$ equals the probability of the last ball being white

Comment: They are choosing $N-1$ white balls from $N + M -1$ balls (and then last ball is essentially $1C1$).

Comment: How many balls are taken out? This information I cannot find.

Comment: Your way of thinking about the probability is correct and agrees with the ultimate "book" answer.  Having two different ways to count is often useful.

Comment: @MathLover I'm not sure I understand. I know they take 1 ball off so that the last 1 will be white, but why choosing $N-1$ balls? I mean in the end $M+N-1$ are taken out from $N+M$, then why looking at combinations of $N$ balls?

Comment: You want to ensure there are only $N-1$ white balls in $N + M -1$ balls.

Comment: How many balls are taken out? This information I cannot find

Comment: @callculus all of them, the question revolves around the color of the last ball